# Extracting XML based on attribute name

Tags: xml, xpath

I have xml with following structure. Want to extract only Name information from following. I am using extract function for this. But for extracting only "Name" what should be my xml path? I tried all ways. Please help how to fill query for this.

```
  <Employee>
      <Basics>
        <Attribute Name="Scope">LOCAL</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="Name">Narendra</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="Id">12345</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="Type">EMPLOYEE</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="Revision"/>
      </Basics>
</Employee>
```

My query is as follows.

```
SELECT 
extract(value(N), 'Attribute/text()').getStringVal() AS Emp_Name    
FROM   Employee A,    
table(xmlsequence(extract(A.XML_INFO, '/Employee/Basics/Attribute'))) N
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xpath, you use predicate (`[]`) to filter element with some specific criteria. For example, you can use the following xpath to get `<Attribute>` element having `Name` attribute value equals `"Name"` :

```
/Employee/Basics/Attribute[@Name="Name"]
```